# elasticsearch maximum number of connections

Tags: elasticsearch, connection, logstash

Is there a configuration variable that I could set on an ES instance that can control the maximum number of client connections? 
What is the default limit on the max connections? 
And how can I change it?
How to connect logstash with Elastic search and how to reuse the connection.